# Can't find Javascript assets in Jasmine specs in Middleman

Tags: jasmine, assets, sprockets, middleman

We're wanting to use middleman-jasmine to run some tests on the generated sites: e.g.

- does the popup contact form appear
- injecting a GeoIP location does it show the nearest office

We've managed to set up Jasmine and it runs a basic trivial test, but I can't see how to require our source JS libs.

we have this structure:

```
source
  js
   thing.js

spec
  js
    spec.js
    thing_spec.js
```

`spec.js` looks like this:

```
//= require_tree .
//= require thing
```

But it can't find `thing`. I've tried every combination of:

```
//= require ../../source/js/thing
//= require ../../build/js/thing
//= require js/thing
//= require js/thing.js
```

None of which work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, discovered the problem. It turns out we had the wrong path in `config.rb`:

`set :js_dir, 'js'`

We incorrectly had 'javascripts' instead of 'js'.

Strangely, it **didn't** affect anything in the rest of the middleman build, but did stop sprockets from finding the asset paths for jasmine.